# How to share printer form ubuntu desktop to other ubuntu desktop

Tags: networking, printing

After 12.10 OEM now I have installed Ubuntu 14.04 and I'm facing the same problem.

Dear Maythux you told me that in Print menu SERVER, PRINTER, GROUP, VIEW, HELP will appear and click on Server to proceed.

but in mine Ubuntu Desktop

There is no option in the top the for SERVER, PRINTER, GROUP, VIEW, HELP.

I have hp1320tn installed and working properly print test page goes well but its not sharing with other Ubuntu Desktop.

I tried a lot but printer sharing didn't done.

How to fix this issue.

Comment: thankyou very much Maythux, but after system-config-printer, Printers- localhost menu appers but there is no server, printer, view, Help options in the menu

Comment: Please stop close-voting as EOL, as this question isn't "**specific** to an end of life Ubuntu release", but applicable to most modern Ubuntu releases (and actually all other Distros that use CUPS, too)

Comment: @the_Seppi This is correct, but 12.10 may have specifics and OP can't install packages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**First you should note Ubuntu 12.10 is outdated and no longer supported by Ubuntu, so you should upgrade to some supported Versions such as 12.04LTS or 14.04LTS or non LTS such as 14.10 and 15.04**

---

Now I'm answering since this would be applicable for all Ubuntu versions. And this since your domain only contains Ubuntu, if some Windows you need samba.

---

The Print Server is the Ubuntu computer that is directly connected to the printers.

On the server machine (the one the printer is attached to), open System -> Administration -> Printing (If the menu item does not exist you need to add system-config-printer to the menu). . This will open the Printer Configuration window.

[image]

Select Server in the menu bar, and then Settings. This will open the Basic Server Settings window.

Check the second box:
Publish shared printers connected to this server If this computer acts as both a Print Server and a client (it does need access to a printer connected to another computer), select also the first box, "Show printers shared by other systems".

[image]

OK

Right click the printer and check the Shared option, if not checked yet

Check that users that you want to be able to use the printer are not excluded or allow printing for all others. See Properties>Access Control. The default settings may be set to "deny printing for everyone except ..."

[image]

PS: If you want to use it with Windows you should use **[samba](https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Samba_as_a_print_server)**

Full documentation and source from : https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NetworkPrintingWithUbuntu

Comment: In Windows, network printers published from a CUPS server can be found and used without problems. No need for SMB.

Comment: but i'm asking you that in the printing local host menu i- server ii- printer iii- View iv- Help didn't appeared. Whats the reason?? what to do next??